# Is it possible to upgrade to the next build of Windows Server insider preview 2019?

Tags: windows-insider

The insider preview expires tomorrow and a message dialog suggests to download the next preview build. I checked updates and there are none. Is it not possible to update to the next build or do you have to constantly reinstall clean builds from scratch in the server insider preview?

Comment: Try opening a admin `cmd` and type `slmgr.vbs /rearm`, then reboot. This should extend the period

Comment: @mt025 Didn't work...

Comment: You didn’t include which build you are using.  So we can’t determine if there has been an iso of a more recent build released.  The command that was suggested would have only worked if we were talking about a licensing issue.  The actual build your using will expire.  Once that happens you will have to reinstall Windows Server 2019

Answer (score 0):

All server preview builds after [February 2018](https://www.ntweekly.com/2018/02/14/windows-server-insider-preview-build-17093-released-place-os-upgrade/), build 17093 can be upgraded in place using the [downloaded ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewserver) and running setup. Just select keep existing settings and files. Windows 10 preview builds can be installed via the updates section in settings.